# Should API secrets be stored in hashed form?

Tags: php, api, security

I want to make an automated connection to an API through a simple cron job. Usually APIs are protected with an API key, right? The API I am working with wants me to send the username and password which is used for the weblogin.

So if I want to create a script for this I'm going to need to store the password. I never want to store this as plain text. But since I'm not storing the 'reference' password but the 'user input' password I can't seem to figure out a way to do this.

Comment: Which service does need the credentials?

Comment: The service that I need to push my information to.

Comment: You should avoid to use someone else's credentials. Unlike credentials, tokens can be rewoked without changing user's password so they are much better. Do you control the service?

Comment: No, i don't control the service. I think it's not a very secure thing to do. I will contact them and ask them to change this in the future, but for now I need to figure out a way to make a connection and not store the password in plain text.

Comment: To me, there doesn't seem to be other way than using plaintext password in this case :(

Comment: I really don't get the down votes on my question. Can't see any reason why this was a bad question.

Comment: Don't worry about the downvotes. I think it might be because it was a brief question, but I think it is interesting (and, importantly, I don't suspect it of being a duplicate) so +1. (There usually isn't much value in adding complaints about voting, since if someone was going to justify their DV, they would probably already have done so. Other readers can only guess).

Answer (score 0):

It's OK to store a plain text password in this context - the difference between services your app needs (i.e. databases and APIs) and customer passwords is that, in the latter case, a customer is on hand to supply the password when it is required. Since a human cannot do this in the former case, it does need to be stored on disk.

It doesn't help security if service passwords are hashed, either. If a hashed password grants a system access to a database to an API, then the hash *is* the password, and thus hashing has increased complexity for zero additional protection. Once an attacker has found a way to read/write your filing system (e.g. via SSH, or uploading an unauthorised script on your disk) then your security has been compromised anyway.

With all that in mind, why is it a good idea to hash and salt user passwords? The reason is that, unfortunately, users often practice the bad security habit of re-using their email/password pairs across several services. If it is discovered (from plain text, reversible encryption, or weak hashing) then it may compromise their security in other places too.

Comment: I agree, I have to store the password on disk, but it will be insecure. If someone will retrieve this, they will be able to login to the we service under this account.

Comment: How would they retrieve it, @StefR? Ensure they cannot do so, and you are reasonably protected. Many modern APIs work this way - they generate a "secret" which must not be shared with anyone outside of a development team.

Comment: Well, even with the best efforts to make everything secure, a security breach is always possible. When a hacker gets a username and a hashed password, he can't do anything because even with the salt he cannot retrieve the original password. The way I'm forced to store the password (unwashed) in the my case the hacker will be able to use the stolen credentials.

Comment: @StefR: But there is a difference in the two cases: with users, you cannot trivially change all their passwords, since it effectively locks everyone out, and there is some inconvenience that might lose you some of your userbase. With APIs, you can change them easily. If you have a need for high security, change the key every month, and add security trip wires to your servers.

Comment: (As I say in my answer, if your attacker can read arbitrary files from your disk, it's probably game over anyway: you would need to discover the hole, close it down, then wipe down and redeploy. At this point they could have installed malware to _collect_ passwords, assuming they have also got write access to the disk).

Comment: I agree. No argument there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which operating system you are running under, but most have facilities to store data encrypted.

Windows has something called [Data Protection API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx). It allows you to encrypt and decrypt data (username and passwords in your case) based on a machine key.

If you run your service under a dedicated account, it will be impossible for other users/application on your machine to decrypt your data.